# Пример предложения, где ОНО будет частицей

Tags: части-речи, частица

Помогите придумать или найти предложение, где *оно* будет являться не местоимением, а частицей.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ОНО**
употребляется в значении частицы в безличных предложениях в качестве неопределенного намека на подлежащее (*прост.*).
*Как оно следует ожидать.* А.Тургенев.
*Конечно, если продать парочку лошадок, да одну из коров, да барашков, оно, может быть, и хватит.* Герцен.
Так оно и вышло. Вот оно что! Оно и видно. Оно и лучше. Оно хорошо бы, да нельзя.
[**Толковый словарь Ушакова**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/902402/%D0%9E%D0%9D%D0%9E)

**ОНО** как частица довольно часто используется в составе сложных сочетаний:
*так вон **оно** что, так вот **оно** что; так-то **оно** так*.

*Ах, **так вот оно что**! Ты решил, что все будет по-прежнему – Сатаниди, подлости, анекдоты?*
Б. Пастернак. Доктор Живаго

***Так-то оно так***, но что общего у этого огромного количества людей?
Б. Акунин. Внеклассное чтение

*Но приходили и сомнения: **так-то оно та**к, да не совсем же так.*
В. Распутин. Прощание с Матерой

[**Знаки препинания при частицах**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%85/)

Answer (score 3):

Из словаря

**II. частица** (с вводным сл. и в безл. предл.). Разг. Усиливает, выделяет слово или высказывание. Оно правильно, что ты сказал. Чаю? Кофе? - Как оно скорее. Я неудачник. - Оно и видно. * Оно, конечно, Александр Македонский герой, но зачем же стулья ломать? (Гоголь). ◊ Вот оно как! Употр. для выражения удивления.

**Вон оно как обернулось! Оно и понятно. Оно и к лучшему.**